# Tabulator : edited cell not showing in table.getEditedCells()

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using **Tabulator** to implement an editable table and I encountered an issue.

The user can either manually edit cells one by one (through a dropdown) or **select multiple cells and click a button to set them all to the same value**.

Then, when the user is done editing, a save button is available and sends everything back to the server.

The save button only saves edited cells (accessed by `table.getEditedCells()`).

My issue is that cells edited through a button (to set a common value for multiple cells) are not marked as *edited*, thus are not present in the `table.getEditedCells()` list.

1. Is there a function to force a cell to be marked as edited ?
2. Or would you have suggestions on how I should change the save button behavior ?

### Some code

At first, the buttons updated the cell values through
`row.update({column:value});` but this didn't trigger the cellEdited callback.
I now use :

```
var cell = row.getCell("field");
cell.setValue(value);
fixEditedCells.push(cell);
```

`cell.setValue` triggers cellEdited callback (the change can now be undone with history `table.undo()` ; that wasn't the case when I used `update`)

My temporary fix is to store the cells modified through the button in an array (`fixEditedCells`) and then merge it with the .getEditedCells() when saving...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Cells only get flagged as edited by user interaction not by use of the 'setValue' function. This is by design to allow developers to update the table without it being registered as an edit by the user.

Comment: Thank you for this precision. However, would there be a way to manually flag a cell as edited ?